# ScrollView rendering takes a lot of time on iOS using Appcelerator

Tags: ios, ipad, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

One of our Appcelerator apps is experiencing rendering delays on IOS platform for the screens where there are multiple widgets (customised textfields to meet client UI requirement) being displayed inside the scrollview.

The screens are making use of **ScrollView where these custom controls (Widgets) are displayed inside the views**. We are seeing the delay in the following scenarios:

- When the screen is having quite a few controls displayed (around 10-15 controls).

It is observed that the rendering time it takes and any changes to this control properties while the page is loading (such as setting some properties by calling the methods on the widget) is resulting in extra 2-3 secs delay.

- When these controls are dynamically added into the page - say in response to the question by the user we display additional controls to capture the information.

We have seen a clear lag in this case which is not good from the user experience perspective.

**Note:**

- All of these issues are only on IOS platform whereas the same code works pretty good (without any lag) on Android platform.
- Tried out using the tableview in place of scrollview but the result is no different.
- Using tableview also results in poor scrolling performance.
- As some complex views are created and added dynamically, using listView would be challenging.

Can anyone let me know if any of you are aware of such issue and how it was resolved (in any appcelerator project)? Is there any way on the native front setting some property/native code through a module that would help speed up the rendering on IOS?

We are only developing for iPads and iPad Minis using iOS 7.1.1+ using Titanium SDK version 5.1.2 (We have tried latest SDKs, but they haven't solved our problem).

Comment: Can you share a code snippet where you are adding those controls in ScrollView, it will help us to solve this issue faster..?

Comment: @PrashantSaini Unfortunately I cannot share the code snippet here directly but I'll try to give you an idea of what we are doing.  There is a parent view on which we are adding some widgets. We are doing that simply by using a Ti.UI.createView and then requiring the widgets and adding them to the above mentioned view. On click of a button in the widget, more views are created using Ti.UI.createView and added to the widget's parent view. It had to be done this way as the views aren't static in our application and has to be generated dynamically based on information downloaded from a server.

Comment: @PrashantSaini The odd thing is that the whole thing is very smooth in Android (even in low end devices) and we haven't used anything different for iOS. This is why we were wondering if anything iOS specific had to be done to optimize the performance of scrollView.

Comment: Try to look in widget's code for iOS as may be there could be some issue. I think you can share screenshots of what you are doing.